# How do I fix this problem printing playing cards using unicode in python?

Tags: python, poker, playing-cards

I am trying to print ascii playing cards for a poker game but it's not working as planned.

I tried printing playing cards using unicode for my poker program in python but when I use the unicode the console comes up with this error:
"SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape"
and when I copy and paste the ascii from the website (which I'd prefer not to do) it only prints cards with a question mark on them

here is my code:

```
backOfCard = '\u+1f0a0'
print(backOfCard)
```

Comment: Where did you get the value `\u+1f0a0`?  Did you copy it from some example?

Comment: oh yeah, there was 2 websites that i tried, this one is from https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/playing-cards/

Comment: The plus sign is wrong but I guess the rest isn't right either. Which unicode number do you actually want to use?

Comment: How do you mean? Preferable these ones: https://www.alt-codes.net/playing-cards-symbols.php

Answer (score 3):

The [syntax for unicode escapes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) in Python is `\uxxxx` for 16-bit values, and `\Uxxxxxxxx` for 32-bit values, so you want `\U0001f0a0`.

(Or `'\N{playing card back}'`.)

Comment: Awesome, the codes working but I'm still just getting them as cards with question marks. I assume I'd have to download something.

Comment: If you get question marks, that probably means that you are using a font that does not have that character.

Comment: I don't follow, I am using default windows font

Comment: @wildflower - where are you displaying the output that you are seeing the `?` output.  It may be using a font that doesn't support any Unicode.
 Another option that isn't included in this answer is to simply put the Unicode characters directly into your script such as ``

Comment: @nigh_anxiety yip i tried that too and it still pops up with the same and it only does this in my console, other text seems fine. My best best bet is creating my own cards with ascii as the suit symbols work fine but the card symbols would be much more efficient.

Comment: @wildflower What are you using for your console, and on which OS?  You may just need to look for info on how to update that to use Unicode, if possible.  Otherwise run your code in an IDE where the terminal programs support Unicode, such as VSCode.